# Scraping data from a related URL column rendered from a Web Scrape/RSS

Tags: web-scraping, google-drive-api, rss

I am scraping data from a site, and each item has a related document URL. I want to scrape data from that document, which is available is HTML format after clicking link. Right now, I've been using Google Sheets to ImportFeed to get the basic columns filled.

Is there a next step that I could do to go into each respective URL and grab elements from the document and populate the Google sheet with them? The reason I'm using the RSS feed (instead of python and BS is because they actually offer an RSS feed.

I've looked, and haven't found a question that matches mine specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't personally tried this yet but I've come across [web scraping samples using App Script](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html) with the use of [UrlFetchApp.fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String)). You can also check the [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service) sample which is also related to scraping.